# How to properly display QChart using QGraphicsScene?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qgraphicsscene, qchart

I would like to display a QChart in my GUI using QGraphicsScene and  QGraphicsView. I tried to do it as follows:

```
chart = QChart()
chart.addSeries(series)        
scene = QGraphicsScene()
scene.setSceneRect(MyGraphicsView.sceneRect())
scene.addItem(chart)
MyGraphicsView.setScene(scene)
```

The problem is that the chart is not resized to the size of the scene, but displayed in its corner. I know, that I could use the QChartView, but I already use this QGraphicsScene in many places of my application and would prefer to have it this way.

Thanks for any suggestions.

[image]
The scene takes almost the whole grey area in the middle and the chart takes only a fraction of it.

Comment: You could show a picture of your current problem and what you want to get

Comment: eyllanesc And what is wrong right now?

Comment: Is that what you require depends on your particular application, you say that occupies the gray area, the gray area depends on how you have placed the other items, do you understand?

Comment: Is it more clear now?

Comment: no, it's not clear. please read [ask] and provide a MCVE